# Getting and remember the selected RadioButton in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have this method in my JavaFx application for creating `RadioButton`s.

```
private HBox createModesRadios(IntegerProperty count, Mode... modes) {
    ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
    HBox result = new HBox(50);
    result.setPadding(new Insets(20, 0, 0, 0));
    result.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    for (Mode mode : modes) {
        RadioButton radio = new RadioButton(mode.getText());
        radio.setToggleGroup(group);
        radio.setUserData(mode);
        result.getChildren().add(radio);

    }
    if (modes.length > 0) {
        group.selectToggle((Toggle) result.getChildren().get(0));
        count.bind(Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> ((Mode) group.getSelectedToggle().getUserData()).getCount(), group.selectedToggleProperty()));

        } else {
        count.set(0);
    }
    return result;
}
```

It is called in my `initialize()` method inside my Controller class in the following way `HBox radioBox = createModesRadios(elementCount, modes);`.

This is the helper class Mode:

```
public class Mode {

private final String text;
private final int count;

public Mode(String text, int count) {
    this.text = text;
    this.count = count;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}
}
```

How can I save the button selected by the user? Would be great to store in a variable `String` the `mode.getText()` method for the selected button. Also I would like to set back the previously selected button, so the app can remember the choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add something like this in the variables declarations inside your controller class: `private List<RadioButton> radioButtonsList = new ArrayList<>();`

Then you can add something like this inside the `for` loop in the method you mentioned

```
...
radioButtonsList.add(radio);
...
```

After that you can call the button you want with `radioButtonList.get()`